Can overloads be distinguished solely by their "where" constraints in C#?
Is it possible to have multiple methods with the same "core" type signature be overloaded based on the where clause constraints?
For example, ideally I'd like to have these two functions:
class DataWriter {
    public void Write<K,V>(string key, Dictionary<K,V> data) 
        where K : ISerializable
        where V : ISerializable { ... }
    public void Write<K,V>(string key, Dictionary<K,V> data) 
        where K : Enum, IConvertible
        where V : ISerializable { ... }
}

As is, this results in error CS0111: Type 'DataWriter' already defines a member called 'Write' with the same parameter types.  This indicates it isn't possible, but I'd like to get either confirmation that it isn't, or the syntax that would make it work.

The purpose of this it to have an abstract serialization mechanism that can deal with different data types.
For example, I'd like to be able to write the code dataWriter.Write("key", someData) and have it do the right thing.
I'm using overloads to distinguish the types as they require different serialization approaches.  It's no problem to distinguish between my custom ISerializable type and the Enum type outside of a collection, but the restriction above makes it hard to distinguish when used in a collection.
I also don't want to do runtime type introspection or reflection where possible.

the fact you want to do that makes me suspect you have an XY problem.

A  Proposal to get that feature into the CLR. I take it as a "not possible" even if the discussion is a few years old.

That workaround, to split into classes, looks interesting. I'm going to see if I can get that to work.

@edA-qamort-ora-y what's the actual problem? This does seam like an attempt to convert concepts from eg C++ to C#. This almost looks an attempt at template specialization.  There may be other, better ways to do this. Template specialization is just a way to solve specific problems, not an end in itself

I added a "purpose" section. I just want to have a single Write syntax that can handle all data types.  And yes, the idea is from similar code I've writing in C++ in the past.

@edA-qamort-ora-y all serializers handle multiple types one way or another. XmlSerializer, System.Text.JSON, JSON.NET handle all possible types without using overloading like this. Even in C++ it's better to use a visitor pattern, allowing you to handle new types in the future without modifying the DataWriter code. This allows creating custom converters for new types too.

In the past serializers used Reflection extensively but lately C#'s pattern matching can be used to match on type, values, properties, conditions etc and drastically simplify the code. Reflection can't be used with AOT compilation, so System.Text.Json uses source generators to generate code specific to various types instead of checking at runtime

Hypothetically, if K implements both ISerializable and IConvertible, how would the correct overload be identified?
